# hello, how do I understand these something like these 0x0023FF4C? any books?

Tags: window

at the above example the "0x0023FF4C" I haven't copied it from anywhere, but I see it most of the time, so I'm quite curios if what does those mean, what do you even call it? thanks

Comment: well I almost forgot it, it's just that I see it everywhere, can't help my curiosity :)

Answer (score 0):

In Programming this could be notation for a hexadecimal number. Call up your windows calclulator, switch it to programming or scientific and you should be able to input 0-9 and a-f, just omit the 0x in front - thats just a marker for "this is hex". 
Read up on f.e. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal - essentially it is a numeric notation with a base of 16 - not 10. Thats why u use a-f in additionto 0-9.

In decimal it's 2359116.[image: win 8.1 calculator programming]

If not a hex-number, it might be a hoax.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer and the tip about the wincalc, but I still haven't tried the link, Hope this is not too much but I just read something about it, it's some sort of memory, thanks anyway